# Grafana: Aggregating query results into alert annotations

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-alerts

Grafana newbie here, I've been messing with this problem and couldn't come up with any solutions. (Sorry my reputation is not high enough to post images...)

### What I want to acheive

I'm trying to implement a high CPU usage alert, as well as providing the top 3 highest cpu usage processes.

### My Parameters

- I have query A monitoring an instance called `grafana-test`
  [image](https://global.discourse-cdn.com/grafana/optimized/3X/5/1/51200426b46f29fb4e645cbda8c152c3d972c0b5_2_1380x178.png)

  and query B getting the top 3 highest cpu usage processes using `process exporter`
  [image](https://global.discourse-cdn.com/grafana/optimized/3X/e/4/e42fbc7d3770fb53e499bae8777be30efc677fdf_2_1380x326.png)
- As for my expressions, I set the threshold as follows, hoping I could get an alert if CPU usage exceeds 70%
  [image](https://global.discourse-cdn.com/grafana/optimized/3X/4/3/43604fcc43a5c1237464004db656da2113b0c2b0_2_828x394.png)
- Here are my annotations
  [image](https://global.discourse-cdn.com/grafana/optimized/3X/9/2/924375bb07570f64da2ed7ac129eec20cb777b3c_2_690x398.png)

When I stress test my vm to CPU 100%, the alert does trigger, however I am not getting any results from query B.

### Expected Results

Grafana Alert send the following message to Slack

> Summary: CPU usage at grafana-test has been above 70% for the last 5 minutes
> Description: CPU usage: 100%
> Top 3 Process
>
> - `stress-ng`: 97.2%
> - `grafana-agent`: 1.8%
> - `google_osconfig`: 0.2%

### Some experiments and the results

I couldn't get a way to output any results from query B, I've tried looking for it in `$values` and tried directly accessing it through `$labels.B0`

- `{{$values}}` outputs only A and C: `map[A:100 C:1]`
- `{{$labels.B0}}`
  outputs `[no value]`

#### What could be the problem? Thanks!